# hope to setup Jenkins Job to build the SQLiteDB and copy to Android asset folder and continue to release build?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to setup jenkins for build the android project, below is the my project setup

I have two projects

1. Android Project With gradle
2. SQLiteBuilder JAVA Project With Maven

I have already created two jenkin Jobs to build Android Project and the SQLIteBuilder Project

JOB: 01 -  Android Project (parameterized)

ex: `gradle assemblerelease -PcampiginId="123465" -PnewAppId="com.abc.check"`

JOB 02 0 SQLiteBuilder Project  (parameterized)

ex: `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.abc.MainApp" -DcampiginId="123465"`

I'm looking for solution which I can merge this two jobs.

I want to trigger the JOB01 (Android Project): 
Which will trigger the JOB02  as a pre-build job and build the SQLiteDatabase and copy it to the Android Project asset folder and continue the JOB 01 to prepare the release build of android apk. (signing/zipalign) and upload to the beta testing.

Is it possible to Add the

```
"mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.abc.MainApp" -DcampiginId="123465"
```

to JOB 01, do the following steps
01 first build the sqlite DB
02 Copy to the Asset Folder
03 Continue with the release build 
04: email the final release apk. 
05 and cleanup the workspace (remove the generated SQLite DB file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to enable "Build Trigger/call builds" features in build steps. Use this to trigger your task.

Comment: I installed that plugin and setup on job01 to trigger the JOB02, It's trigger JOB02 build after completing the JOB01. I need it to trigger the job as a prerequisites job to JOB01

Comment: @Sam how are you triggering the job01, manual or polling SCM ¿?.